# ASP.NET Sorting Multiple SQL Database Tables By Date Range

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

This past week I was tasked with moving a PHP based database to a new SQL database.  There are a handful of requirements, but one of those was using ASP.Net MVC to connect to the SQL database...and I have never used ASP.Net or MVC.

I have successfully moved the database to SQL and have the foundation of the ASP site set up (after spending many hours pouring through tutorials).  The issue I am having now is that one of the pages is meant to display a handful of fields (User_Name, Work_Date, Work_Description, Work_Location, etc) but the only way of grabbing all of those fields is by combining two of the tables.  Furthermore, I am required to allow the user to search the combined table for any matching rows between a user inputted date range.

I have tried having a basic table set up that displays the correct fields and have implemented a search bar...but that only allows me to search by a single date, not a range.  I have also tried to use GridView with its Query Builder feature to grab the data fields I needed (which worked really well), but I can't figure out how to attach textboxes/buttons to the newly made GridView.  Using a  single table with GridView works perfectly and using textboxes/buttons is very intuitive.  I just can't seem to make the same connection with a joined view.

So I suppose my question is this: what is the best way for me to combine these two tables while also still having the ability to perform searches on the displayed data?  If I could build this database from scratch I would have just made a table with the relevant data attached to it, but because this is derived from a previously made database it has 12+ years of information that I need to dump into it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am kind of dead in the water here.  My inexperience with these systems is getting the better of me.  I could post the code that I have, but I am mainly interested in my options and then I can do the research on my own.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a bit confusing. Is *a PHP database* a MySQL database, or something else? When you say you moved it to *a new SQL database*, do you mean an SQL Server database, or something else? You might consider showing your table definitions (the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE something`. Please [edit] your question to give more details. Also, you may find it helpful to read up on SQL `JOIN` operations.  Thanks!

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pzwRwYlXMw&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v&index=1  Specially the part for Entity Framework so you can bring the data with his related tables at once.

Comment: I received a PHP dump of the old PHP database and had to convert it to a MSSQL database.  Thank you for posting the tutorial.  I will be sure to check it out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to offer definitive answers to your questions due to the need for guesswork.

But here are some hints.

1. You can say `WHERE datestamp >= '2017-01-01' AND datestamp < '2018-01-01'` to filter all the rows in calendar year 2017. Many variations on this sort of date range filter are available.
2. Your first table probably has some kind of ID number on each row. Let's call it `first.first_id`. Your second table probably has its own id, let's call it `second.second_id`. And, it probably has another id that identifies a row in your first table, let's call it `second.first_id`.  That `second.first_id` is called a foreign key in the second table to the first table.  There can be any number of rows in your second table corresponding to your first table via this foreign key.

If this is the case you can do something like this:

```
 SELECT first.datestamp, first.val1, first.val2, second.val1, second.val2
   FROM first
   JOIN second ON first.first_id = second.first_id
  WHERE first.datestamp >= '2018-06-01' AND first.datestamp < '2018-07-01'
    AND (first.val1 = 'some search term' OR second.val1 = 'some search term')
  ORDER BY first.datestamp
```

This makes a virtual table by joining together your two physical tables (`FROM...JOIN...`).

Then it filters the rows you want from that virtual table (`FROM ...`).

Then it puts them in the order you want (`ORDER BY...`).

Finally, it chooses the columns from the virtual table you want in your result set (`SELECT ...`).

SQL database servers  (MySQL, SQL Server, postgreSQL, Oracle and the rest) are *very* smart about doing this sort of thing efficiently.

Comment: This is an excellent option.  I've got that data displaying correctly as per the client's request.  Now I'll research how to implement user input and I'll be good to go.  Thank you for the response!